# Can 1 gameobject (screw) detect another gameobject (screw nut) and then create animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm building an engineer Augmented reality app,.

Basically I want 1 game object which is the screw, detect another game object which is the screw nut, then if the two detected each other they will connect. (create animation that it is connecting like the screw is rotates through the hole).

So the questions are: 
1) how will the one object (active) will detect the another object (passive)? 
2) how can i set it to real time size detection like if this screw is not fitted then it will not connect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Add a proper tags to your objects, e.g. tag diameter_5mm. Add a collider with isTrigger enabled to one kind of items and attach a script with something like that:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if (other.tag == transform.tag){
        //let the magic begin!
    }
}
```